# SVG use multiple, load once

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I want to use the same SVG twice on my page, but only load it once.

I'm manipulating the CSS of the SVG with JS, so I think the SVG needs to be in directly in the HTML as opposed to using an object.

The manipulation is the same for both SVG's, they should be exact replica's, so I really don't want to have to load it twice.

Any way for me to do this?

Thanks,
James

Comment: Could you provide an example of the code you're using to load, manipulate and insert the SVGs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```css
svg {
   color: green;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- define SVGs -->
<div style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; width: 0px; height: 0px;">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 18 15" id="sample">
    <path d="M17.9 1.85L7.675 12.318 6 14.03l-1.676-1.713L.1 8.002c-.15-.162-.146-.43.01-.597l1.07-1.15c.155-.168.403-.172.554-.01L6 10.605 16.266.094c.15-.163.4-.16.555.008l1.07 1.152c.156.167.16.435.01.596z" fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
    </symbol>
  </svg>
</div>

<!-- and use it whenever you want -->
<svg><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#sample"></use></svg>

<svg><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#sample"></use></svg>
```

Comment: xlink:href is deprecated and MDN recommends to avoid it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href

Comment: @koedev what would be an appropriate alternative to using xlink:href

Comment: found the answer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use You should use `href="#sample"`